# Error using a positive lookbehind in a bash script sed on OSX

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I am working on manipulating a string (BRANCH_NAME) and removing the front characters up to the forward slash.  This is being used to change commit messages in git.

For example, the branch 'feature/pux-1234' is to be changed to pux-1234.  There are different value that may exist, exclusive of each other.  In this first attempt, I am checking for two values: feature/ and hotfix/.

Here is the code:

```
# Remove everything up to the first slash if it exists
if  [[ $BRANCH_NAME == *"/"* ]]; then
  PRETRIM=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -E 's/(?:(?<=feature\/)|(?<=hotfix\/)).+/' )
else
  PRETRIM = $BRANCH_NAME
fi
```

The error I am receiving is this:

> sed: 1: "s/(?:(?<=feature/)|(?< ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Ideas to help resolve?

Comment: `sed` doesn't support look behind. Use `perl`

Comment: `sed` doesn't implement PCRE, it implements BRE by default. You can use the `-E` option to get ERE, but there's no option for PCRE.

Comment: No no lookarounds at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, the branch `feature/pux-1234` is to be changed to `pux-1234`

You don't need a lookbehind here and anyway `sed` doesn't support look arounds.

You can use capture groups in `sed` to match all options in one group and replace with empty string:

```
s='feature/pux-1234'
sed -E 's~(feature|hotfix)/~~' <<< "$s"
```

```
pux-1234
```

and

```
s='hotfix/pux-1234'
sed -E 's~(feature|hotfix)/~~' <<< "$s"
```

```
pux-1234
```

---

Using `extglob`, you can can do this in `bash` itself:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${s/+(feature|hotfix)\/}"
```

```
pux-1234
```